# Login with Google: How to programmatically open prompt for user consent and get the CredentialResponse on success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, google-signin, react-google-login

I am trying to trigger the Prompt for User Consent to open on clicking a custom html button rather than the Login iframe button rendered by Google. I am using [Sign In With Google JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference) and I didn't found a function to do this, but I found a way to do this [using the token model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model) and [using the Code Model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model) but these gives me token/code in the callback, but I need a [CredentialResponse](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#CredentialResponse) in callback, is there any way to do this ? I am trying to create Vue/React plugins to easily implement Sign In With Google,One-tap sign-up and Automatic sign-in features in Vue/React applications, but I am stuck now.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [@react-oauth/google](https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth) it uses the new google service identity SDK,
with `useGoogleLogin()` custom hook it can be used with your custom button.

and you can check the implementation of the hook to do the same work in vue

Comment: Thank you [Mo'men Sherif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18040354/momen-sherif), but this library uses `google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient` or `google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient` under the hoods right??? So in the callback response we only gets either access token or an Auth Code right? I need a function which gives JWT  credential string just like the response we get from One-Tap Prompt success callback

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanBaji you can follow this issue will tell you how to get JWT using authorization code flow with custom hook
https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth/issues/12#issuecomment-1131408898